# Moving duplicate record to another table before deleting

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, insert-into

I found this great code which deletes duplicate rows in a SQL Server table.

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
      (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3 ORDER BY id)
  FROM dbo.tbl
)
DELETE x WHERE rn > 1;
```

Now I want to **move the duplicate records to another table before deleting**. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just change the `delete` to `select * into [table]  from x` or `insert into [table] select * from x` (obviously including the `where` you already have).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply copy-paste the CTE and use it twice:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
      (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3 ORDER BY id)
  FROM dbo.TableName1
)
INSERT INTO dbo.TableName2
    SELECT columns FROM x WHERE rn > 1;

;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
      (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3 ORDER BY id)
  FROM dbo.TableName1
)
DELETE FROM x WHERE rn > 1;
```